# Flexslider next previous buttons font not displaying

Tags: button, navigation, flexslider

please see : http://barrel12.weebly.com/

I implemented the flexslider after changing the locations for all fonts and images and js/css. But the buttons are still coming in the font and not the front and back buttons as in the [real version of flexslider.][1] http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

I know that they are not images and fonts, but its still not coming right. I can't figure out what have I left..

Can anyone suggest how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I fixed it.
Copy "FlexSlider-master/fonts"(file you downloaded) document to your host, next to flexslider.css